# How to use batch to explore the files and sub directories of a .zip file

Tags: batch-file, directory, zip

I realize this question is stretching the capabilities of batch scripting, but is there a way to view the files and directories of a .zip file without unzipping the file? For example, say there is a .zip file named `myfile.zip` and has a subdirectory called `status` which contains a `status.xml` file. Is there a way to view the contents of the `status.xml` file through the batch scripting language?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using the 7zip from the command line, e.g. `7z -l myzipfile.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various zip command line utilities will allow you to list the contents of the zip archive, but you said you also wanted to view the contents. You can view the contents by extracting the file from the archive. [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) will do it as mentioned above. [Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/) also has a couple of command line utilities that do the same (you can find the binaries [here](http://www.willus.com/archive/zip64/)).

If you want to view the contents of status.xml without having to write the file to disk, you can pipe it out using the [unzip.exe](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html) command line utility from Info-Zip.

```
unzip -p myfile.zip status.xml | more
unzip -p myfile.zip status.xml > status.xml
```

To use the same utility to list the zip file's contents:

```
unzip -l myfile.zip
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Although I was looking for more of a standalone approach, the unzip command worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without external tools with [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f):

```
call zipjs list -source C:\\myZip.zip -flat no
call zipjs list -source C:\\myZip.zip\\inZipDir -flat yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip.js to get data from the `myzip.file`, 
here is a part of the code:

```
zipFs.importHttpContent("1.zip", false, function() {
    var firstEntry = zipFs.root.children[0];
    console.log(zipFs)
    firstEntry.getData64URI("image/png",function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
}, onerror);
```

======================

the origin code is from http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/